# How to impose $\phi=0$ to the solution of a Helmholtz decomposition of a divergence-free field?

Tags: mathematics, vector-fields

As stated here, [Uniqueness of Helmholtz decomposition?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10522/uniqueness-of-helmholtz-decomposition) , the solution of the Helmholtz decomposition is not unique.

Suppose that, for given vector field $\mathbf F$ with $\nabla \cdot \mathbf F =0$, I have **a** solution of its Helmholtz decomposition: the pair $\phi$ and $\mathbf A$. They are such that: $$\mathbf F = -\nabla \phi + \nabla\times\mathbf A.$$

What kind of transformation can I apply to $\phi$ and $\mathbf A$ to find another pair $\phi_1$ and $\mathbf A_1$ such that $$\nabla \phi_1 = 0$$ and $$\mathbf F=\nabla \times \mathbf A_1 $$?

Answer (score 1):

The transformation you want is, in general, impossible. The reason is that curls have zero divergence, but if the gradient is nontrivial then your vector field will have nonzero divergence, so it can't be modelled as only a curl.

Comment: Hi Emilio, thanks a lot for your answer. I should have specified (which I'll do now, editing my question) that my vector field $\mathbf F$ has zero divergence. If this is the case, I suppose a transformation should exist.

Comment: If it has zero divergence, and you choose boundary conditions that are strong enough for uniqueness, then phi will naturally be zero. If you have good reasons why you don't want to impose such conditions then I guess it becomes a bit more complex of a question but I'd say you really need to say what those reasons are.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, it is probably indicating what direction I should take to solve my problem. My field F is actually a magnetic field, therefore must have div(F) = 0.  In particular it's a magnetic field given in form of field map (three 3d Cartesian meshes: one for Bx, one for By, and one for Bz). Unfortunately this field map represents a truncated field, which doesn't go to zero at the boundaries. Do you think that, if I had a field map which zeroes at the boundaries, my computation of $\phi$ and $\mathbf A$ should be as I desire (i.e. $\nabla \phi=0$) ?

Comment: Given that I compute $\phi$ and $\mathbf A$ following the method explained in http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2005JA011382/full , I must admit I don't really know how to fix the boundary conditions to achieve $\nabla \phi = 0$.

Comment: I guess there is some legitimate cause for wanting what you're asking for, but I don't have time at the moment - I'll look into it if I find some time.

Comment: Alright. Thank you again, Emilio. I suspect a change of reference system (rotation + translation?) might help achieve the desired condition. I need to figure out if this is true, and how to compute such a transformation automatically and efficiently.

Comment: No, a change in reference system won't help at all. You need to solve the differential equation $\nabla\times \mathbf A= \nabla \phi$ for $\mathbf A$, so you'll need a bit more machinery.

Comment: Hi Emilio, just a quick update, for your info: eventually I verified that applying a rotation of the axes has indeed the effet of "moving the field information" from $\phi$ to $\mathbf A$, and vice versa; and I could (almost completely) vanish the scalar potential as I desired. The reason why this happens becomes manifest if one writes the expressions of the scalar and of the vector potentials in the Fourier space. Of course, once the field is reconstructed from the rotated vector potential, one needs to counter-rotate the result to go back to the original XYZ set of coordinates.

Comment: @HansCastrop That looks pretty bogus to me but without more details it's impossible to tell what it is you're actually doing.

Comment: It is all based on the idea presented in the paper I cited few comments earlier. In particular formulae (1) and (4), which provide a recipe to extract the scalar and the vector potentials of a field map, based on the Fourier Transform. But some fields can feature both scalar and vector potentials simultaneously. As the FT commutes with any axes rotation, one can calculate *the* rotation that minimizes the dot product in (4), which in turn minimizes the FT of $\phi$ (and therefore $\phi$). Once $\phi$ eliminated, one can use $\mathbf A$ from the rotated field.

Comment: @HansCastrop That sounds like complete hogwash to me, but suit yourself.

Comment: "Hogwash" sounds a little dismissive to me. If you have concrete objections to the correctness of this method, could you please articulate them?

Comment: @HansCastrop As I said, there's not enough details to judge the method's merits. I would recommend that you post a separate answer with how you're resolving this (which is the ideal course of action, anyways, so that future visitors that find this through search engines can find an answer), I can probably comment further.

Comment: Try a gauge transformation $\mathbf A \rightarrow \mathbf A + \nabla \phi$?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me one can perform any transformation
$$ \phi\rightarrow\phi+\phi_0 ~~~~~~ {\bf A}\rightarrow{\bf A}+\nabla f , $$
provided that $\nabla\phi_0=0$ (which means $\phi_0$ is a constants). The result after the transformation should give the same ${\bf F}$.

Am I missing something?